# Is it recommended to change Geoserver admin username?

Tags: geoserver, security

The docs and a bunch of other questions on here are circulated around changing the default password for admin on GeoServer. I know it's highly recommended to change the default password for the admin account for security reasons, but what about the admin username?

Is it standard practice to change the admin username for security purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the admin user name to something other than `admin`.  This doesn't upset Geoserver (i.e. it is not reserved).  I have never seen any recommendation saying you ***should*** do this, but, to my way of thinking, changing the admin user name to something less obvious is a tiny little bit of extra security (giving a hacker two things to guess/crack).  I do this on Geoserver instances I set up for that very reason.

**AFTERTHOUGHT:** Note that the admin account is different to the root account (much like root in Linux). You can't change the username of root but can and should change its master password as well as admin's password